# Rearranging existing PDF:s with overflow (only on centerfold pages)

Tags: pdf, context, imposition

Working with ConTeXt to imposition a 16 page A6-folder to print double sided on A3 paper and it works!

The problem is that the centerfold in my case pages 8-9 because don't overflow. (it is a 16 page folder). Can I give a command that the topspace should only affect the centerfold?

This is how it looks like with the topspace set to 0 pt and as shown in the picture it leaves a gap between page 8-9 that should not be there. Se the white stripe through the picture on the left.

[image: This is how it looks like without the topspace set to -1.5pt]

And here is the pdf-file:
[pomfritt_sista.pdf](http://maggan.dk/temp/pomfritt_sista.pdf)!

This is the code is about "Rearranging existing PDF s" and it is from [context garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition#Default_schemas)and the -1.5pt solved pages 8-9 but putting the other pages to close to eachother.

```
\setuppapersize[A6][A3] %individual page A6 size, print size A3
\setuparranging[2*8, rotated] %makes an 8 page gathering when folded (duplex printing!)
\setuplayout
  [backspace=0pt,
    topspace=0pt, %here I can add -1.5pt to make images overflow on centerfold pages but it will go on all pages
       width=middle,
      height=middle,
    location=middle,
      header=0pt,
      footer=0pt]
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\starttext

\insertpages
  [pomfritt_sista.pdf][width=0pt]

\stoptext
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so we can help you better.

Comment: I cannot reproduce without `pomfritt_sista.pdf`

Comment: @HenriMenke Added the file!

Comment: Which version of ConTeXt are you using and which program do you use to view the file?  With ConTeXt 2016.05.17 19:20 MKIV and the Evince viewer  I cannot reproduce the problem ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMB55.png)).

Comment: @HenriMenke ConTeXt Process Management 0.63 used it with TeX Shop 3.62 on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite.

The file are then viewed in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Also changed the code to be the faulty one for reproducing. If you change the value to the one in the comment you will see the change. 1.5pt is a very small change but when cutting the pages later on the will be offset.

Comment: Also the code is from this page http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition#Default_schemas

Comment: »ConTeXt Process Management 0.63« is not the version of ConTeXt.  Execute `context --version` and see what it says under `current version`.  It should be a date and a time.

Comment: @HenriMenke 2016.05.17 19:20, same as you.

Comment: Trying to find a workaround with this (I print the cover separate so it is not really the issue here but the code seems to be able to put into my project)

Comment: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition#Getting_to_the_Back_Cover_of_a_Booklet

Comment: I gave up. I printed with the -1.5pt setting and I hope I will solve it in the cutting machine after folding.

Comment: Since this is not reproducible and you haven't updated the question for year, I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I solved it with the script posted.

Comment: A pdf of scanned result is linked on my homepage

Comment: http://skru.pl/er/pomfritt